# Java Memory Ocupation

Tags: java, performance, memory

i made a server side aplication that uses 18mb of non-heap and around 6mbs of head of a max of 30mbs. i set the max of heap with -Xms and Xmx, the problem is that when i run the program on ubuntu server it takes arround 170mbs instead of 18+30 or atleast 100Mbs in the max. Some one know how to put VM only getting 100MBs?

Comment: What is your use case for this? Do you aim to have 100s of VMs running on the same server?  Normally when running a java process on a server, you wouldn't really care if you are using 100MB or 30MB, as memory is cheap.

Comment: The values you have set for Xms and Xmx would help here. And how is it that you that you believe your application should/must take only 48 MB (18+30) of memory?

Comment: i have made some tests with Jconsole and VMvisual. Xmx 40mbs Xms 25. the problem is that iam restricted to 512mbs since its a VPS and i can't pay for it now. The other thing is that with 100mbs each i could put atleast 3 process's running...

Comment: 28114 meu       22   0  161m  20m 5744 S    0  3.9   0:05.22 java
here is a top print

Answer (score 0):

The JVM uses heap, other memory like thread stacks and share libraries.  The shared libraries can be relatively large but they don't use real memory unless they are actually used. If you run JVMs they are shared between them but you cannot see this in the process information.

In a modern PC, 1 GB of memory costs around $100 so reducing every last MB many not be seen to be as important as it used to be.

Comment: Its a VPS and it's limited to 512Ram. its a server application

Comment: In that case the provider might have some suggestions, or a forum for the them. The JVM can consumes a lot of virtual memory which doesn't turn into real memory, you have to watch the resident size.

Comment: 28114 meu 22 0 161m 20m 5744 S 0 3.9 0:05.22 java here is a top print

Comment: If I am reading this right, its using 161m of virtual memory and 20m of resident memory (i.e. main memory) If you ran another JVM it might look time the memory is doubling up, when actually its shared (as long as it the same Java install) You need to run the application for a while as the shared libraries might get brought in some more.  Note: if you run low on memory they can be pushed out again.

Comment: A simple trick to find out the minimum your applications can run in is to create a large file as big as your memory and then delete it.  This pushes out any pages which are not being used and you will see how much of the applications have to stay in memory.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment

> i have made some tests with Jconsole
>   and VMvisual. Xmx 40mbs Xms 25. the
>   problem is that iam restricted to
>   512mbs since its a VPS and i can't pay
>   for it now. The other thing is that
>   with 100mbs each i could put atleast 3
>   process's running.

The problem is, you are going about it the wrong way. Don't try and get your VM super small so you can run 3 VMs. Combine everything into 1 VM. If you have 512 memory, then make 1 VM with 256MB of heap, and let it do everything. You can have 10s or 100s of threads in a single VM. In most cases, this will perform better and use less total memory than trying to run many small VMs.

Comment: yeh i normal do it when the program is the same, but the problem is that this is diferent things i cant union them :S

Comment: You always COULD union them... but you are right, sticking 3 random programs together is not that ideal...

Comment: I think that you've got an tradeoff problem here.  You've got to make tradeoff decisions around cost and maintainability.  Is it worth the cost for extra RAM in your environment, to avoid the complexity to jam the different applications into the same runtime, or is it not?  If the answer is that you can't accept either, then you need to start thinking about the expense of running in a VM and make a tradeoff about writing your stuff in C, where you can closely control the memory used (tradeoff there being the expense of rewriting your app, and in a non-VM environment).